# There is an additional 8 minutes time

Tags: time, laravel-4

I have this code:

```
<td>{{date('h:m A',strtotime($sched->time_out))}}</td>
```

It retrieves time value from the database. But the time that it returns or that is displayed has an additional of 8 minutes. For example the time that is being stored on the database is 07:00:00 the value that being returned is 7:08 AM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PHP dates, `m` stands for **month**. What you need is `i`:

```
<td>{{date('h:i A',strtotime($sched->time_out))}}</td>
```

[Here is a reference table for all format characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)